# Using malloc to store coordinates in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc

I am writing a program and the part I am working on at the moment must take hundreds of triangles (that form a 3D shape) and store the coordinates of each triangle. For example, one triangle will have coordinates: (x1, y1, z1) (x2, y2, z2) (x3, y3, z3).
I think perhaps organising a struct in this way would be a start (but I am open to better ideas..!)

```
struct triangle {
  double x1;
  double y1;
  double z1;
  double x2;
  double y2;
  double z2;
  double x3;
  double y3;
  double z3;
};
```

Essentially, I wish to be able to store each triangle's coordinates and then at another point in the program I would like to go back and delete some triangles and add some others to the 'list'.
I've been trying to do this for days now and any help would be much appreciated - it's driving me crazy...

Thanks in advance! Let me know if I can explain anything in better detail.

Comment: `struct coord { double x, y, z; }; struct triangle { struct coord coords[3]; };`?

Comment: That's very helpful - I'm not too sure how to implement malloc in this case. Thank you :)

Comment: You shouls show the (unsuccessful) results of "trying to do this for days" and explain what exactly you are having problems with. If you use something like an array (instead of a list) and want to delete data you must either handle unused array elements or move all data after the deleted element to close the "hole".

Comment: The problem is that I've picked up C over the past couple months and have been able to write the code to build an STL file of triangles but I need a more reliable way of storing the triangles which will then make it easier to edit the list by adding/removing. I haven't been able to figure malloc out yet especially if it involves a struct. I try to figure things out on my own but I'm at my wits end and really need an explanatiomn for my application. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Depending on the frequency and number of triangle 'objects' you have to add/remove it is not trivial to manage such handling in a fast and efficient way. To not go too deeper I suggest you to start defining the base object, the triangle set, then connect them using linked lists. The linked lists allows easy add/removal of objects from the chain, but aren't the fastest or more efficient way. Anyway it could be a base to investigate for more effective methods (maybe with google help...).

Comment: Managing containers in c in a good way may not be the easiest thing to do after only having picked up c "in the last couple of months". Are you sure you want to do this in c? There are many fine languages out there with richer container types than c, no shame in using those. Use the right tool for the job. If you are doing this as a learning experience on the other hand, be ready to learn a lot...

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to use a more user-friendly structures as:

```
struct coord_s {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}

struct triangle_s {
    struct coord_s points[3];
}
```

Then, as far as malloc is concerned, you can allocate a *pointer* to a struct using malloc as such `struct triangle_s *my_triangle = malloc(sizeof(struct triangle_s));`

sizeof() will take care of calculating the size of the actual structure and send it to malloc()

Then you just need to choose what to use as storage depending on your use case

Comment: When I try this I get an error saying 'initializer element is not constant' :( I thought I was a competent coder in C but when it comes to malloc I'm useless no matter how hard I try..!

Comment: are you sure you copied the structure the same way I did?  you might have used '[]' instead of [3]

Comment: Minor nitpick: `malloc(sizeof(struct triangle_s))` doesn't allocate a pointer. It allocates memory for a single `struct triangle_s`, and returns a pointer to it.

Comment: Good alterantive to `my_triangle = malloc(sizeof(struct triangle_s));` --> `my_triangle = malloc(sizeof *my_triangle);`  Easy to code right, review and maintain.  Why risk coding the wrong type?